# SequelizeAssociationError after second call

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using a NodeJS webservice to receive my database data. If I call the methode the first Time everything works as expected.

I want to receive all entries from my table with all associations with the following Code:

```
    model.hasOne(devicemodel, {foreignKey: 'id',sourceKey:'deviceid'});
    model.hasOne(usermodel, {as: 'client', foreignKey: 'id' ,sourceKey: 'clientid'});
    model.hasOne(usermodel, {as: 'operator', foreignKey: 'id' ,sourceKey: 'operatorid'});


    var rma = await model.findAll({
        include: [devicemodel, {model: usermodel, as: 'client'}, {model: usermodel, as: 'operator'}],
        where: {
            itoakid: config.companyid
        }
    });
    return callback(rma);
```

But at the second call I get the following error:

> SequelizeAssociationError: You have used the alias client in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases.

I'm using Sequelize Version 6.11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the associations **every time the route is hit** and your function executes.

Move the schema declaration out the route handler and place it after you define your schema:

```
                class Model extends Sequelize.Model {}

                Model.init({
                    id: {
                        primaryKey: true,
                        type: Sequelize.UUID
                    },
                    ...
                }, {
                    sequelize,
                    modelName: 'model'
                });

               sequelize.models.model.hasOne(...
```

In your route handler:

```
               var rma = await sequelize.models.model.findAll({
                  include: [devicemodel, {model: sequelize.models.usermodel, as: 'client'},
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to define the associations in your route, you can check existing associations prior to define.

alternative way,

```js
    model.hasOne(devicemodel, {foreignKey: 'id',sourceKey:'deviceid'});
    if( !model.hasAlias('client') ){
        model.hasOne(usermodel, {as: 'client', foreignKey: 'id' ,sourceKey: 'clientid'});
    }
    if(!model.hasAlias('operator')){
        model.hasOne(usermodel, {as: 'operator', foreignKey: 'id' ,sourceKey: 'operatorid'});
    }


    var rma = await model.findAll({
        include: [devicemodel, {model: usermodel, as: 'client'}, {model: usermodel, as: 'operator'}],
        where: {
            itoakid: config.companyid
        }
    });
    return callback(rma);
```

The best way, you should define associations once as `@Samuel G` mentioned